# Cannot browse network shares in Windows Explorer, but paths are still accessible

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-explorer, network-shares

Windows Explorer has somehow corrupted itself and I'm not sure how to fix this problem. My Windows installation has been in use for a few years with network shares setup and working. Recently, I noticed that a program that I use to save network share paths to a database was no longer opening the explorer window to browse the path. It usually opens to the last path saved, but now it was just not opening at all.

When I go to Windows Explorer to browse the network share directly, I get the error `\\SERVER is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. The specified network provider name is invalid.` The network shares are just shares on the server itself (once saved to the database, they're used on the server as well as clients to reach files).

The strange thing is, the files are still accessible from the program that uses them if I type the network share path in manually. So it is only a problem with Windows Explorer browsing the path.

The reason I think there is some sort of configuration or setting, possibly in the registry, corrupted is that when the problem first manifest itself, I was somehow able to open an explorer window to a network share path, but the breadcrumb in the address bar did not function properly. It duplicated the share name folder at the top of the breadcrumb stack and when I clicked the second of the duplicated share folder, it crashed explorer.exe. I haven't been able to browse any network share path since this happened.

I have tried using the IP address directly `\\192.168.1.#` as well as `\\localhost` and neither of those work either. I have tried running `sfc /scannow` and it did not find any errors. I tried `ipconfig /flushdns` and this made no difference. Attempting to map the network share to a drive fails using either the explorer GUI or `net use` command.

Is there some way to reset Windows Explorer somehow to resolve this? I'd really like to avoid reinstalling Windows entirely if I can.

Comment: Have you got any restore points?

Comment: I tried restoring to my earliest restore point and this did not fix it.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: Yes, the same issue exists after performing a clean boot.

Comment: Does it happen using any user account? Did you try [resetting the TPC/IP stack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357/en-us)?

Comment: Yes it happens for all users. I reset the TCP/IP stack and it didn't fix it. The issue does not seem to be with the network interface, but rather specific to Windows Explorer. I can reach the network share paths in the program I'm using them in. I just can't browse to them in either a Windows Explorer window or a file/folder browser in the database program (which uses the Windows Explorer interface).

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [start Windows in Safe Mode with Networking](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode#1TC=windows-7)? Also, you said that mapping the network share to a drive letter fails. What's the error message you get, exactly?

Comment: Attempting to map it in Windows Explorer gives the same error as attempting to browse to the network share. Using the `net use` command, the error is: `System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14883/discussion-between-and31415-and-jeff-lockhart).

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Explorer to "access a server directly" is a bit of a misnomer. by typing in simply "\servername" or "\serverIP" into Explorer, it's not going to try to give you access to the "root" directory. Rather, it's going to try to provide you with a list of all shares on that server (or at least, shares that you have permissions to view).

Say you have a Windows network file share server. On that server, you have a folder structure like this: D:\stuff\things\JeffShare. Your coworker wants to access the files in the "JeffShare" folder across the network, so you create a Share named "JeffShare" with a *network* path of "\fileserver\JeffShare" and grant the coworker access.

Now, just because your coworker has network access to the "JeffShare" folder, this does not necessarily mean that the coworker has access to the "things" folder above it. If the coworker does not have access to the "things" folder and they try to access it over the network using "\fileserver\stuff\things" they will get a message saying either it is inaccessible or that they don't have access to it.

Take a look at the share setup and see if "Access-based enumeration" is enabled. If it is and you don't have security permissions to the network location or path you're trying to access, you'll also be denied.

Unfortunately, Windows isn't always consistent in letting you know the exact reason you can't access a network location. You'll have to do a little investigation into the share setup and the actual folder permissions to determine if you're being denied at the share level or at the folder security level.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).